# How to filter Android Firebase database query properly for RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a list of categorized alimentaries, which users can mark as favorites.

Here a sample Database:

```
{
  "alimentaries" : {
    "chocolate" : {
      "name" : "Chocolate",
      "category" : "sweet"
    },
    "big_tasty" : {
      "name" : "Big Tasty",
      "category" : "meal",
      "users" : {
        "userA" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "userA" : {
      "name": "James",
      "alimentaries" : {
        "big_tasty" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "categories" : {
    "meal" : {
       "name" : "Meal",
       "alimentaries" : {
         "big_tasty" : true
       }
    },
    "sweet" : {
       "name" : "Sweet",
       "alimentaries" : {
         "chocoalate" : true
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The query for the normal full list is:

```
Query ref = mDatabaseReference.child("alimentaries").orderByChild("name");
```

I need to show a list of all alimentaries, which is no problem using the FirebaseRecyclerView.

But now I need:

1. Filter the normal list by a selected category
2. Show another list containing only the alimentaries marked as favorite by the current user (userA), which may be filtered by category too

Both lists need to be ordered by the alimentaries name property.

Comment: Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also your Firebase Database structure. That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: One way to do this is by using FirebaseUI's Indexed adapters. I just answered a question that needed that, so will refer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467195/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-database-with-join-if-key-only-return-true

Comment: Reading your database as a "JSON object" is very confusing. Some of those values should be lists.

Comment: As far as i know, Firebase Database needs to have all entries to be JSONObjects

Comment: The Indexed adapters works well to get the favorites. But they are not ordered alphabetically by the alimentaries names. How to achieve that?