# How to retrieve data from Firebase Database with join if key only return true?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to ask how to retrieve group that only user2 join in Android?

```
"users": {
    "user1": {
        "name": "User 1"
    },
    "user2": {
        "name": "User 2"
    }
}

"groups": {
    "groupA": {
        "name": "A Group"
    },
    "groupB": {
        "name": "B Group"
    }
}

"userGroup": {
    "user1": {
        "groupA": true,
        "groupB": true
    },
    "user2": {
        "groupB": true
    }
}
```

I already try
`DatabaseReference userGroupRef = rootRef.child("userGroup/user2")`
but cannot show the name of the groups

But if I use
`DatabaseReference groupsRef = rootRef.child("groups")`
the group that `user2` not joining also showing.

Does firebase has a query like `groupsID in userGroup/user2`?

**Edit_1**

I use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to show the list from `rootRef.child("groups")` that shows all the groups even if user2 is not joining.

```
groupsRef = rootRef.child("groups");

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Group, GroupHolder>(Group.class, R.layout.group_item_layout, GroupHolder.class, groupsRef) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(GroupHolder viewHolder, Group group, int position) {
        viewHolder.setGroupName(group.getName());
    }
};
groupRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: show the code how you retrieve the values

Comment: I use `FirebaseRecyclerView` like the updated explanation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use-case is specifically addressed by the [`FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data). You pass in two references/queries: one for the so-called index (the keys with `true` values that you want to show) and one for the actual object that you want to load for each matching key.

In your case:

```
groupsRef = rootRef.child("groups");
indexRef = rootRef.child("userGroup/user2");

FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter <Group, GroupHolder>
  (Group.class, R.layout.group_item_layout, GroupHolder.class, indexRef, groupsRef) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(GroupHolder viewHolder, Group group, int position) {
        viewHolder.setGroupName(group.getName());
    }
};
```